# Erro de retorno de código em Java

Tags: java

[Imagem com texto do desáfio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRE3k.png)

Com base no texto da imagem, criei o seguinte código em Java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
        String arquivoDoPc = leitor.next();

        String[] nomeEExtensao = arquivoDoPc.split(".mp3");
        String extensao = nomeEExtensao[0];

        if (extensao.equals(".mp3")) {
            System.out.println("Salvar");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Deletar");
        }
    }
}
```

Quando insiro: "minhasamigas.png" obtenho como retorno "Deletar". Quando insiro: "Californication.mp3", obtenho "Salvar". Até aí, tudo certo, porém quando insiro: "deixaacontecer.mp3", o código me retorna "Deletar". Gostaria de alguma luz nesse problema. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Tanto "Californication.mp3" quanto "deixaacontecer.mp3" resultam em "Deletar".

O valor da variável `extensao` nunca será "mp3", pois o método `split()` descarta o argumento que vc passou para ele.

Por exemplo, considere o código abaixo:

```java
public class App {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    {
      String[] nomeEExtensao = "Californication.mp3".split(".mp3");
      String extensao = nomeEExtensao[0];
      System.out.println(extensao);
    }

    {
      String[] nomeEExtensao = "deixaacontecer.mp3".split(".mp3");
      String extensao = nomeEExtensao[0];
      System.out.println(extensao);
    }
  }
}
```

Ele irá imprimir o seguinte:

```sh
Californication
deixaacontecer
```

Ou seja, ele simplesmente mostra o nome do arquivo sem a extensão.

O que vc precisa é fazer algo assim:

```java
public class App {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    String[] nomeEExtensao = "Californication.mp3".split("\\.");
    String extensao = nomeEExtensao[nomeEExtensao.length - 1];

    if ("mp3".equals(extensao)) {
      System.out.println("É MP3!");
    }
  }
}
```

Note que eu usei `nomeEExtensao[nomeEExtensao.length - 1]` ao invés de apenas pegar a segunda posição usando `nomeEExtensao[1]`.

Fiz isto porque o nome do arquivo pode conter pontos em outras posições do nome, tipo "Cali.forn.ica.tion.mp3", e se eu confiasse que a extensão estaria sempre na segunda posição do array, o resultado poderia não ser o esperado. Por isso eu pego sempre a última posição, que é onde a extensão deveria estar.

De qualquer forma, há jeitos melhores de alcançar o mesmo resultado, como por exemplo, usando o método `endsWith()`. Veja:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
  private static final Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String... args) {
    String arquivoDoPc = leitor.next();

    if (arquivoDoPc.endsWith(".mp3")) {
      System.out.println("Salvar");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Deletar");
    }
  }
}
```